# Equivalent of chain.doFilter in Grails

Tags: java, grails, servlet-filters

In Java, in a filter we could do:

```
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

This mean we could use our own `RequestWrappers` and do:

```
chain.doFilter(new RequestWrapper(request), response);
```

What is the equivalent to `chain.doFilter` in grails? I would like to create my `RequestWrapper` and then invoked the `doFilter` so that the next Filter gets it?

Comment: Isn't grails a Java web application framework? Then, you can use a Servlet Filter as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grails filters (as described [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters)) are not implemented as servlet filters.  I don't think that grails filters provide a way to wrap the request.

You might be able to achieve the same effect by taking advantage of the dynamic nature of groovy.  For example, you could modify the metaClass of the request object to delegate certain methods to another object.

Another alternative is to use a regular servlet filter:

1. Create a class that extends `javax.servlet.Filter` in `src/groovy` or `src/java`.
2. Run `grails install-templates` (if you haven't already).
3. Update `src/templates/war/web.xml` to include `<filter>` and `<filter-mapping>` elements exactly as you would with a pure Java web app.

Comment: If using a Servlet 3.0 compliant application server like Tomcat 7, you just need to decorate the filter class with `@WebFilter("/path/to/apply/*")` and no need to configurate the filter in web.xml.